# Bizarre CGImage from file in CCSPrite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to create a CCSprite from an image on disk. The file is definitely valid image, and I want to display it on a CCLayer. I'm using this code to display the image:

```
    // from a CCLayerColor
    CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(@"/documents/pathto/file.jpg");
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    self.sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:image key:@"sprite_frame_01"];
    self.sprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    [self setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    [self addChild:self.sprite];
```

However, when the scene is rendered I see this (The CCSprite is the numbers with the white background around it):

[image: Buggy CCSprite]

This happens no matter what image use. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"file.jpg"]?

Comment: I tried that but rendered a blank image. From the documentation, is `[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"file.jpg"]` not for resources deployed with the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that cocos2d was auto-appending `-ipad` to the image filename, which didn't exist since it was from the camera roll. I fixed it using  `[[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] setiPadSuffix:@""];`.

I don't have any specific iPad or retina specific files in my app, but for those that do, abica wrote an excellent method on the [cocos2d forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14253#post-81038) which shows how to handle this on a per-file basis.